# Drawer of native base is not working

Tags: android, react-native, drawer, native-base

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Drawer, Container, Header, Left, Button, Icon } from "native-base";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Navigator,
  BackHandler
} from "react-native";

// var PayPal = require('react-native-paypal');
import profileStyle from "./Styles/profileStyle";
import images from "./images";
import OriDash from "./ori_dashboard";

export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false
    };
    this.closeDrawer = this.closeDrawer.bind(this);
    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
  }
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this._drawer._root.close();
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
    // alert("here");
    this._drawer._root.open();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Drawer
          ref={ref => {
            this._drawer = ref;
          }}
          content={<OriDash navigator={this._navigator} />}
          onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
        >
          <Container>
            <Header>
              <Left>
                <Button
                  transparent
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.openDrawer();
                  }}
                >
                  <Icon
                    name={"ios-home"}
                    style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "#00c497" }}
                  />
                </Button>
              </Left>
            </Header>
          </Container>
        </Drawer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as Drawer tag is removed container gets visible otherwise container content is also not getting shown.Can anyone help me with the Drawer component and how to open menu on click of it.I have created a component OriDash where the contents of menu would be shown, and on click of ios-home icon menu should get opened and closed respectively.

Comment: I copied everything from your Container section into my test app, where I'm using a Provider parent instead of a View, and my own component for the Drawer's content.  The page displays with the header having a Home icon, and the drawer works, in that I can swipe from the left edge of the screen to open it.  The Home button in the header also opens the drawer.  I'm wondering if your View should come from native-base instead of react-native?